# BlueSnap API - metadata per transaction

Tags: metadata, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am integrating with the BlueSnap gateway using the Payment API and converting from Stripe. Does BlueSnap Support storing meta data at the transaction level?

Answer (score 2):

Yes additional information pertaining to a transaction can be send using the transaction-meta-data element. You can include up to 20 metadata key-value pairs in transaction-meta-data element.

More information about how to use metadata within the BlueSnap Payment API can be found here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/auth-capture#section-auth-capture-with-metadata